# what is difference between ColumnLabelProvider and ITableLabelProvider in Jface tableviewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, tableviewer

I am working on JFace `Tableviewer`. I am bit confused in the usage of `ColumnLabelProvider` and `ITableLabelProvider`. I am trying to color certain row in the tableviewer(which has 1 column of string and checkbox images in the other 3 columns). I have implemented `ITableLabelProvider` and colored the row but after that editing support is disabled. So I am confused whether should I use `ColumnLabelProvider` or `ITableLabelProvider`?

Can someone suggest me some ideas? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ITableLabelProvider` uses one label provider to provide the labels for all the columns.

`ColumnLabelProvider` uses a separate label provider for each column. It is intended to be used with `TableViewerColumn`:

```
TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(.....);

TableViewerColumn col1 = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEAD);

col1.setLabelProvider(column label provider for col 1);

col1.setEditingSupport(editing support for col 1);

... repeat for other columns
```